# PHP Mysql Json encode and Arabic language

Tags: php, json

I used

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

and

1. MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
2. MySQL connection collation: `utf8_general_ci`
3. your database and table collations are set to: `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`

and every time I try to output the json by using `echo json_encode($return_arr);`
I get like this

```
[{"item_id":"497c5fe455811cb88d66d98da7e11abd","title":""\u0627\u0644\u064a\u0648\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u0633\u0627\u0628\u0639": \u0645\u0641\u0627\u062c\u0623\u0629.. \u0642\u0627\u0646\u0648\u0646 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0631\u0647\u0627\u0628 \u0645\u0647\u062f\u062f \u0628\u0639\u062f\u0645 \u0627\u0644\u062f\u0633\u062a\u0648\u0631\u0
```

Comment: That's the usual escaping for Unicode symbols.

Comment: And what is your question?